# Optimizing a Python synth on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, audio, raspberry-pi

For the past few weeks I have been working on a project which is all very new to me, and I'm learning as I go. I'm building a synthesizer using a Raspberry Pi 2 and I'm coding it in Python3, as I have some basic knowledge of the language, but not much real experience. I've muddled through pretty well so far, but I have now hit the wall I knew I would hit eventually: performance.

I have been using Pygame and its Sound module to create the sounds I want, and then using my own mathematical algorithms to calculate the ADS(H)R volume envelope for every sound. I tweak this envelope using 8 potentiometers. 3 of them control the length in seconds of the Attack, Decay, Release and another one to set the Sustain level. Then I added 4 more pots which control the curvature of each part of the envelope (except one of them instead sets a Hold value for Sustain). I have a PiTFT screen connected as well which draws up the current shape and length of the entire envelope, as well as prints out the current values of ADSR.

To play sounds I use a 4x4 Adafruit Trellis board and with different button combinations I can play every note between C0 and C8.

I use SciPy and NumPy to create different kinds of soundwaves, as in Sine, Square, Triangle, Sawtooth, Pulse and Noise.

As I have been using regular for loops to change the volume of the sound according to the ADSR envelope, running the function PlaySound takes a while to complete (depending on my ADSR settings of course). This prompted me to try using threads. I don't know if I'm using it in the best way, of if I should use it at all, but it was the only way I could think of to achieve polyphony. Otherwise it had to wait until a sound was completed until it would resume the main loop. So now I can play several notes at the same time. Well, two notes at least. After that it lags and the third one doesn't seem to play until one of the previous sounds have finished.

I've done some tests and checks and I should be able to runt up to 4 threads at the same time, but I might be missing something. One guess is that the system itself has reserved two threads (cores) for other usage.

I realize also that Python is not the most efficient language to use, and I've been looking into Pure Data as well, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it (I prefer code over a click-and-drag-gui). I want to keep using Python for as long as possible. I might look into using pyo, but I think I'd have to mostly start from scratch with my code then (which I am willing to do, but I don't want to give up on my current code just yet).

So. Here's my question(s): How can I optimize this to be truly polyphonic? Two notes is not enough. Should I skip the threads altogether? Can I implement the ADSR envelope in a better, less costly way? How can I clean up my messy math? What other performance bottlenecks are there, that I have overlooked? The Pygame drawing to the screen seems to be negligable at the moment, as there is virtually no difference at all if I disable it completely. Here is my code so far:

```
import pygame
from pygame.mixer import Sound, get_init,  pre_init, get_num_channels
from array import array
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import alsaaudio
import time
import Adafruit_Trellis
import Adafruit_MCP3008
import math
import _thread
import os
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal as sg
import struct

#print(str(multiprocessing.cpu_count()))

os.putenv('SDL_FBDEV','/dev/fb1')

fps = pygame.time.Clock()

FRAMERATE = 100
MINSEC = 1/FRAMERATE

BLUE       = (  0,   0, 255)
WHITE     = (255, 255, 255)
DARKRED = (128,   0,   0)
DARKBLUE   = (  0,   0, 128)
RED     = (255,   0,   0)
GREEN     = (  0, 255,   0)
DARKGREEN  = (  0, 128,   0)
YELLOW   = (255, 255,   0)
DARKYELLOW = (128, 128,   0)
BLACK     = (  0,   0,   0)

PTCH = [ 1.00, 1.059633027522936, 1.122324159021407, 1.18960244648318, 
    1.259938837920489, 1.335168195718654, 1.414067278287462, 
    1.498470948012232, 1.587767584097859, 1.681957186544343, 
    1.782262996941896, 1.888073394495413, 2.00 ]

FREQ = {  # Parsed from http://www.phy.mtu.edu/~suits/notefreqs.html
    'C0': 16.35, 'Cs0': 17.32, 'D0': 18.35, 'Ds0': 19.45, 'E0': 20.60,
    'F0': 21.83, 'Fs0': 23.12, 'G0': 24.50, 'Gs0': 25.96, 'A0': 27.50,
    'As0': 29.14, 'B0': 30.87, 'C1': 32.70, 'Cs1': 34.65, 'D1': 36.71,
    'Ds1': 38.89, 'E1': 41.20, 'F1': 43.65, 'Fs1': 46.25, 'G1': 49.00,
    'Gs1': 51.91, 'A1': 55.00, 'As1': 58.27, 'B1': 61.74, 'C2': 65.41,
    'Cs2': 69.30, 'D2': 73.42, 'Ds2': 77.78, 'E2': 82.41, 'F2': 87.31,
    'Fs2': 92.50, 'G2': 98.00, 'Gs2': 103.83, 'A2': 110.00, 'As2': 116.54,
    'B2': 123.47, 'C3': 130.81, 'Cs3': 138.59, 'D3': 146.83, 'Ds3': 155.56,
    'E3': 164.81, 'F3': 174.61, 'Fs3': 185.00, 'G3': 196.00, 'Gs3': 207.65,
    'A3': 220.00, 'As3': 233.08, 'B3': 246.94, 'C4': 261.63, 'Cs4': 277.18,
    'D4': 293.66, 'Ds4': 311.13, 'E4': 329.63, 'F4': 349.23, 'Fs4': 369.99,
    'G4': 392.00, 'Gs4': 415.30, 'A4': 440.00, 'As4': 466.16, 'B4': 493.88,
    'C5': 523.25, 'Cs5': 554.37, 'D5': 587.33, 'Ds5': 622.25, 'E5': 659.26,
    'F5': 698.46, 'Fs5': 739.99, 'G5': 783.99, 'Gs5': 830.61, 'A5': 880.00,
    'As5': 932.33, 'B5': 987.77, 'C6': 1046.50, 'Cs6': 1108.73, 'D6': 1174.66,
    'Ds6': 1244.51, 'E6': 1318.51, 'F6': 1396.91, 'Fs6': 1479.98, 'G6': 1567.98,
    'Gs6': 1661.22, 'A6': 1760.00, 'As6': 1864.66, 'B6': 1975.53, 'C7': 2093.00,
    'Cs7': 2217.46, 'D7': 2349.32, 'Ds7': 2489.02, 'E7': 2637.02, 'F7': 2793.83,
    'Fs7': 2959.96, 'G7': 3135.96, 'Gs7': 3322.44, 'A7': 3520.00,
    'As7': 3729.31, 'B7': 3951.07,
    'C8': 4186.01, 'Cs8': 4434.92, 'D8': 4698.64, 'Ds8': 4978.03,
}

buttons = ['A',PTCH[9],PTCH[10],PTCH[11],'B',PTCH[6],PTCH[7],PTCH[8],'C',PTCH[3],PTCH[4],PTCH[5],PTCH[12],PTCH[0],PTCH[1],PTCH[2] ]

octaves = { 'BASE':'0', 'A':'1', 'B':'2', 'C':'3', 'AB':'4', 'AC':'5', 'BC':'6', 'ABC':'7' }

class Note(pygame.mixer.Sound): 

    def __init__(self, frequency, volume=.1): 
        self.frequency = frequency 
        self.oktostop = False
        Sound.__init__(self, self.build_samples()) 
        self.set_volume(volume) 

    def playSound(self, Aval, Dval, Sval, Rval, Acurve, Dcurve, Shold, Rcurve, fps):
        self.set_volume(0)
        self.play(-1)
        if Aval >= MINSEC:
            Alength = round(Aval*FRAMERATE)

            for num in range(0,Alength+1):
                fps.tick_busy_loop(FRAMERATE)
                volume = (Acurve[1]*pow(num*MINSEC,Acurve[0]))/100
                self.set_volume(volume)
                #print(fps.get_time()," ",str(volume))
        else:
            self.set_volume(100)

        if Sval <= 1 and Sval > 0 and Dval >= MINSEC:
            Dlength = round(Dval*FRAMERATE)

            for num in range(0,Dlength+1):
                fps.tick_busy_loop(FRAMERATE)
                volume = (Dcurve[1]*pow(num*MINSEC,Dcurve[0])+100)/100
                self.set_volume(volume)
                #print(fps.get_time()," ",str(volume))
        elif Sval <= 1 and Sval > 0 and Dval < MINSEC:
            self.set_volume(Sval)
        else:
            self.set_volume(0)

        if Shold >= MINSEC:
            Slength = round(Shold*FRAMERATE)
            for num in range(0,Slength+1):
                fps.tick_busy_loop(FRAMERATE)

        while True:
            if self.oktostop:
                if Sval > 0 and Rval >= MINSEC:
                    Rlength = round(Rval*FRAMERATE)
                    for num in range(0,Rlength+1):
                        fps.tick_busy_loop(FRAMERATE)
                        volume = (Rcurve[1]*pow(num*MINSEC,Rcurve[0])+(Sval*100))/100
                        self.set_volume(volume)
                        #print(fps.get_time()," ",str(volume))
                self.stop()
                break

    def stopSound(self):
        self.oktostop = True

    def build_samples(self): 
        Fs = get_init()[0]
        f = self.frequency
        sample = Fs/f 
        x = np.arange(sample)

        # Sine wave
        #y = 0.5*np.sin(2*np.pi*f*x/Fs)

        # Square wave
        y = 0.5*sg.square(2*np.pi*f*x/Fs)

        # Pulse wave
        #sig = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x)
        #y = 0.5*sg.square(2*np.pi*f*x/Fs, duty=(sig + 1)/2)

        # Sawtooth wave
        #y = 0.5*sg.sawtooth(2*np.pi*f*x/Fs)

        # Triangle wave
        #y = 0.5*sg.sawtooth(2*np.pi*f*x/Fs,0.5)

        # White noise
        #y = 0.5*np.random.uniform(-1.000,1.000,sample)
        return y  


pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((480, 320))
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

CLK  = 5
MISO = 6
MOSI = 13
CS   = 12

mcp = Adafruit_MCP3008.MCP3008(clk=CLK, cs=CS, miso=MISO, mosi=MOSI)

Asec = 1.0
Dsec = 1.0
Ssec = 1.0
Rsec = 1.0

matrix0 = Adafruit_Trellis.Adafruit_Trellis()
trellis = Adafruit_Trellis.Adafruit_TrellisSet(matrix0)
NUMTRELLIS = 1
numKeys = NUMTRELLIS * 16
I2C_BUS = 1
trellis.begin((0x70, I2C_BUS))

# light up all the LEDs in order
for i in range(int(numKeys)):
    trellis.setLED(i)
    trellis.writeDisplay()
    time.sleep(0.05)
# then turn them off
for i in range(int(numKeys)):
    trellis.clrLED(i)
    trellis.writeDisplay()
    time.sleep(0.05)


posRecord = {'attack': [], 'decay': [], 'sustain': [], 'release': []}
octaval = {'A':False,'B':False,'C':False}
pitch = 0
tone = None
old_tone = None
note = None
volume = 0
#m = alsaaudio.Mixer('PCM')
#mastervol = m.getvolume()
sounds = {}
values = [0]*8
oldvalues = [0]*8
font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 22)


while True: 
    fps.tick_busy_loop(FRAMERATE)

    #print(fps.get_time())
    update = False
    #m.setvolume(int(round(MCP3008(4).value*100)))
    #mastervol = m.getvolume()
    values = [0]*8
    for i in range(8):
        # The read_adc function will get the value of the specified channel (0-7).
        values[i] = mcp.read_adc(i)/1000
        if values[i] >= 1:
            values[i] = 1
    # Print the ADC values.
    #print('| {0:>4} | {1:>4} | {2:>4} | {3:>4} | {4:>4} | {5:>4} | {6:>4} | {7:>4} |'.format(*values))
    #print(str(pygame.mixer.Channel(0).get_busy())+" "+str(pygame.mixer.Channel(1).get_busy())+" "+str(pygame.mixer.Channel(2).get_busy())+" "+str(pygame.mixer.Channel(3).get_busy())+" "+str(pygame.mixer.Channel(4).get_busy())+" "+str(pygame.mixer.Channel(5).get_busy())+" "+str(pygame.mixer.Channel(6).get_busy())+" "+str(pygame.mixer.Channel(7).get_busy()))

    Sval = values[2]*Ssec
    Aval = values[0]*Asec
    if Sval == 1:
        Dval = 0
    else:
        Dval = values[1]*Dsec
    if Sval < MINSEC:
        Rval = 0
    else:
        Rval = values[3]*Rsec

    if Aval > 0:
        if values[4] <= MINSEC: values[4] = MINSEC
        Acurve = [round(values[4]*4,3),round(100/pow(Aval,(values[4]*4)),3)]
    else:
        Acurve = False
    if Dval > 0:
        if values[5] <= MINSEC: values[5] = MINSEC
        Dcurve = [round(values[5]*4,3),round(((Sval*100)-100)/pow(Dval,(values[5]*4)),3)]
    else:
        Dcurve = False
    Shold = values[6]*4*Ssec
    if Rval > 0 and Sval > 0:
        if values[7] <= MINSEC: values[7] = MINSEC
        Rcurve = [round(values[7]*4,3),round(-Sval*100/pow(Rval,(values[7]*4)),3)]
    else:
        Rcurve = False

    if update:
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

        scrnvals = ["A: "+str(round(Aval,2))+"s","D: "+str(round(Dval,2))+"s","S: "+str(round(Sval,2)),"R: "+str(round(Rval,2))+"s","H: "+str(round(Shold,2))+"s","ENV: "+str(round(Aval,2)+round(Dval,2)+round(Shold,2)+round(Rval,2))+"s"]

        for line in range(len(scrnvals)):
            text = font.render(scrnvals[line], True, (0, 128, 0))
            screen.blit(text,(60*line+40, 250))

        # Width of one second in number of pixels 
        ASCALE = 20
        DSCALE = 20
        SSCALE = 20
        RSCALE = 20

        if Aval >= MINSEC:
            if Aval <= 1:
                ASCALE = 80
            else:
                ASCALE = 20
            # Attack
            for yPos in range(0,101):
                xPos = round(pow((yPos/Acurve[1]),(1/Acurve[0]))*ASCALE)
                posRecord['attack'].append((int(xPos) + 40, int(-yPos) + 130))

            if len(posRecord['attack']) > 1:
                pygame.draw.lines(screen, DARKRED, False, posRecord['attack'], 2)

        if Dval >= MINSEC:
            if Dval <= 1:
                DSCALE = 80
            else:
                DSCALE = 20
            # Decay
            for yPos in range(100,round(Sval*100)-1,-1):
                xPos = round(pow(((yPos-100)/Dcurve[1]),(1/Dcurve[0]))*DSCALE)
                #print(str(yPos)+" = "+str(Dcurve[1])+"*"+str(xPos)+"^"+str(Dcurve[0])+"+100")
                posRecord['decay'].append((int(xPos) + 40 + round(Aval*ASCALE), int(-yPos) + 130))

            if len(posRecord['decay']) > 1:
                pygame.draw.lines(screen, DARKGREEN, False, posRecord['decay'], 2)

        # Sustain
        if Shold >= MINSEC:
            for xPos in range(0,round(Shold*SSCALE)):
                posRecord['sustain'].append((int(xPos) + 40 + round(Aval*ASCALE) + round(Dval*DSCALE), int(100-Sval*100) + 30))

            if len(posRecord['sustain']) > 1:
                pygame.draw.lines(screen, DARKYELLOW, False, posRecord['sustain'], 2)

        if Rval >= MINSEC:
            if Rval <= 1:
                RSCALE = 80
            else:
                RSCALE = 20
            # Release
            for yPos in range(round(Sval*100),-1,-1):
                xPos = round(pow(((yPos-round(Sval*100))/Rcurve[1]),(1/Rcurve[0]))*RSCALE)
                #print(str(xPos)+" = (("+str(yPos)+"-"+str(round(Sval*100))+")/"+str(Rcurve[1])+")^(1/"+str(Rcurve[0])+")")
                posRecord['release'].append((int(xPos) + 40 + round(Aval*ASCALE) + round(Dval*DSCALE) + round(Shold*SSCALE), int(-yPos) + 130))

            if len(posRecord['release']) > 1:
                pygame.draw.lines(screen, DARKBLUE, False, posRecord['release'], 2)

        posRecord = {'attack': [], 'decay': [], 'sustain': [], 'release': []}

        pygame.display.update()

    tone = None
    pitch = 0
    time.sleep(MINSEC)
    # If a button was just pressed or released...
    if trellis.readSwitches():
        # go through every button
        for i in range(numKeys):
            # if it was pressed, turn it on
            if trellis.justPressed(i):
                print('v{0}'.format(i))
                trellis.setLED(i)

                if i == 0:
                    octaval['A'] = True
                elif i == 4:
                    octaval['B'] = True
                elif i == 8:
                    octaval['C'] = True
                else:
                    pitch = buttons[i]
                    button = i


            # if it was released, turn it off
            if trellis.justReleased(i):
                print('^{0}'.format(i))
                trellis.clrLED(i)
                if i == 0:
                    octaval['A'] = False
                elif i == 4:
                    octaval['B'] = False
                elif i == 8:
                    octaval['C'] = False
                else:
                    sounds[i].stopSound()

        # tell the trellis to set the LEDs we requested
        trellis.writeDisplay()

    octa = ''
    if octaval['A']:
        octa += 'A'
    if octaval['B']:
        octa += 'B'
    if octaval['C']:
        octa += 'C'
    if octa == '':
        octa = 'BASE'

    if pitch > 0:
        tone = FREQ['C0']*pow(2,int(octaves[octa]))*pitch


    if tone:
        sounds[button] = Note(tone)
        _thread.start_new_thread(sounds[button].playSound,(Aval, Dval, Sval, Rval, Acurve, Dcurve, Shold, Rcurve, fps))
        print(str(tone))

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: I don't know if it is feasible to do this in PyGame, I would try to use something that allows you to define an audio callback function. You can probably find some inspiration from this example of mine: https://github.com/spatialaudio/jackclient-python/blob/master/examples/midi_sine_numpy.py. This is using JACK, but it should be easy to translate this for use with the [pyaudio](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) or [sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/) module.

Answer (score 1):

what you are doing at the moment, is firing a sound and giving up all control, until that sound has been played. The general approach here would be to change that and process one sample at a time and push that to a buffer, that is played back periodicaly. That sample would be a sum of all your voices/signals. That way, you can decide for every sample, if a new voice is to be triggered and you can decide how long to play a note while already playing it. One way to do this would be to install a timer, that triggers a callback-function every 1/48000 s if you want a samplingrate of 48kHz.

You could still use multithreading for parallel processing, if you need to process a lot of voices, but not one thread for one voice, that would be overkill in my opinions. If that is nescessary or not depends on how much filtering/processing you do and how effective/ineffective your program is.

e.g.

```
sample_counter = 0
output_buffer = list()

def callback_fct():
    pitch_0 = 2
    pitch_1 = 4
    sample_counter += 1     #time in ms
    signal_0 = waveform(sample_counter * pitch_0)
    signal_1 = waveform(sample_counter * pitch_1)
    signal_out = signal_0 * 0.5 + signal_1 *0.5
    output_buffer.append(signal_out)
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    call_this_function_every_ms(callback_fct)
    play_sound_from_outputbuffer() #plays sound from outputbuffer by popping samples from the beginning of the list.
```

Something like that. the waveform() function would give you sample-values based on the actual time times the desired pitch. In C you would do all that with pointers, that overflow at the end of the Wavetable, so you won't have to deal with the question, when you should reset your sample_counter without getting glitches in the waveform (it will get real big realy soon). But I am shure, there are more "pythonic" aproaches to that. Another good reason to do this in a more low level language is speed. As soon as you involve real DSP, you will count your processor clock ticks. At that point python may just have too much overhead.

Comment: So, if I were to set a sampling rate of 1kHz to begin with, the function would run every 1/1000 s and calculate the sum of sounds at that very moment and play it for 1 millisecond, and then the next millisecond it would repeat this. Do you have any example code? Even pseudo code would be helpful. :)

Comment: You wouldn't play back one millisecond, but rather push everything to a ringbuffer, thats let's say 100ms long. and play it constantly. If you dont push something to it, it will repeat every 100ms. That way your computationlenghts are allowed to vary a little bit. I'll put some code in the answer, since writing code in the comments hurts.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that python is probably one of the bottlenecks. Commercial soft-synths are, almost without exception, written in C++ to leverage all kinds of optimization - the most pertinent of these is use of vector processing units.

There are, nonetheless, plenty of optimizations open to you in Python:

- You are calculating the envelope every sample, and in an expensive way (using `pow()` - which is not totally hardware accelerated on ARM Cortex CPUs.  You can potentially pre-compute the transfer function and simply multiply this with each sample.  I also suspect that at 44.1kHz or higher, you don't need to change the envelope every sample - perhaps every 100 or so is good enough.
- Your oscillators are also calculated per-sample, and as far as I can tell, per note playback.  Some of them are fairly cheap, but trig functions less so,   Practical soft-synths use oscillator wave-tables and phase-accumulator as an approximation.

Things you have less control of

- Accuracy: You are ultimately generating a 16-bit sample. I suspect that by default Python is using double precision for everything - which has a 48-bit mantissa - about 3 times wider than you need.
- Double-precision maths functions are slow on ARM Cortex A parts - significantly so in fact.  Single precision can go via the VPU with many operations you would use a lot in DSP such as MAC (multiply-accumulate) taking a single cycle (although they take something like 16 cycles to clear the pipeline). Double precision is orders of magnitude slower.

@Rantanplan's answer above alludes to the kind of software architecture soft-synths are built with - one which is event driven, with a render-handler called upon periodically to supply samples.   A polyphonic softsynth an do these in parallel.

In a well optimized implementation the processing of each sample for each voice would involve:
 * One lookup from the wave-table (having first calculated the buffer offset using integer maths)
 * multiplication by the envelope 
 * Mix the sample with others in the output buffer.

The key to performance is that there are almost no flow control statements in this tight loop.

Periodically, possibly per callback interval, the envelope would be updated. This parallelizes for several adjacent samples at once on CPUs with VPUs - so that would be two-ways on an ARM Cortex A part.

Comment: Some of what you wrote went over my head, but some helped as well. I'm still not sure how to practically write my code using an audio buffer but I'm looking into external tools to help me along, such as FluidSynth and pyo. From what I can gather from both your and @Rantanplan s answes I may have been able to produce sound, but in the least effective way possible (thus unsustainable) which I already suspected. I have much more to learn, and I think I at least know where to start now. :)